# zeromq receive times out with EGAIN exactly the 255th time

Tags: c#, zeromq

library: clrzmq4 (https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq4) in a c# project.

I am using zmq router-dealer configuration. The server is written in python and runs on linux. My dealer client written in c# runs on a windows machine. It sends messages and waits from the response

```
        public Boolean sendMessage(Dictionary<String, String> msgDict)
        {
            ZError err;
            String errStr;
            var reqFrame = new ZFrame(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msgDict));
            retval = socket.Send(reqFrame, out err);
            if (err != null)
            {
                errStr = String.Format("Error while sending command {3} {0} {1}", err.Text, err.Number, err.Name);
                return false;
            }

            err = null;

            respFrame = socket.ReceiveFrame(out err);

            if (err != null)
            {
                errStr = String.Format("Error while receiving response data {0} {1} {2} {3}", err.Text, err.Number, err.Name, num_messages);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
       }
```

I set the sendTimeout and receiveTimeout on the socket to 2 min each.
When I keep calling sendMessage, exactly at the 255th time, receiveFrame timesout . On the server I see the message being processed and response being sent like everytime. And after this point, my send also timesout with the same error "EAGAIN" Resource temporarily unavailable.

There are the things I tried

1. Data with different lengths from 2 KB to 20 MB
2. set the sendhighwatermark and receivehighwatermark to different values: 10, 1000, 10000
3. Tried polling on the socket instead of ReceiveFrame
4. Tried making the sockets completely blocking.

In each of the above cases the failure occured at exactly the 255th time. In case of blocking sockets, it got blocked at the 255th time too.

I can't use netmq as much as I would like to because it doesn't have curvezmq and the server needs it.

I also tried a dealer client from another linux machine and it had no issues 255th time or even later.

Comment: Do you probably get multiple messages? You can check for them, after `ReceiveFrame`, you do `bool more = socket.ReceiveMore`... If there are, you need to receive them all (until the `ReceiveMore` returns false).

Comment: or you use `ReceiveMessage` to get a `ZMessage` and `msg[0]` is your `ZFrame`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried ReceiveMessage and also poll but the issue persists. fails exactly the 255th time. find it very strange as no one else seems to have a problem.

Comment: @metadings figured out the issue, but not the fix yet. When I turn off curve auth I can send thousands of messages with no issues. When I turn on the auth I get stuck at 255.